# Are "wpbt0.dll" errors related to a virus?

Tags: windows, virus

I encountered some errors related to `wpbt0.dll` last week. [This topic](http://www.spywareremovalhelp.org/malware-removal-help/how-to-fix-wpbt0-dll-errors-and-how-to-get-rid-of-wpbt0-dll-malware.html) reported that `wpbt0.dll` is a virus, and also recommended to use Avast to remove it.

Is that true?

Comment: Upload this dll to Virus Total
https://www.virustotal.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a virus on my PC. AVG picked it up, and removed it.

I now get an error saying it's missing when I restart, but I am now able to use my PC properly again. I just need to find out where it's being referenced. Couldn't initially see it in the registry.

What makes me think it's a virus is that it was installed in `App\LocalData\Temp`.